# How to edit MSI product version without using ORCA

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want an automated solution to edit the product version in MSI without using ORCA or edit the format of the product version to accept 4 digits (ex.1.0.0.2)

Comment: What I did some time ago was to edit the MSI's project file in a prebuild step to define the version number, which was way easier than modifying the MSI after it was built

Comment: How? I tried to change it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337338/c-sharp-net-apps-product-version-not-updating-in-control-panel-program-u like how it is explained here but I got an error (Error 98 Invalid product version '1.0.0.2'. Must be of format '##.##.####'").

Comment: MSI doesn't support 4 digit version